# Dynamic bandwith sharing in SonicWall

Tags: sonicwall, bandwidth

In Sonicwall, we "split" T1 line into two lines: Internal LAN (so we can get on the internet) and Client line (so clients can work with server that we host).

We simply dedicated 25% of bandwidth to our Internal LAN, and rest is given to client line. (25/75 ration was found through trial and error) Problem is - 25% is very,very slow for our office needs. And at the same time, clients are not using all the 75% all the time.

Is there way to make this speed dynamically adjustable, because clients are not using entire 75% of bandwidth all the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the guaranteed bandwidth along with the maximum allowed bandwidth for each connection.  So, for example, you can set your guaranteed bandwidth to 25% with a max of 75% on the Internal policy, while setting the Client policy to guarantee 50% with a max of 75%.

This means that if the client policy isn't using all of the bandwidth allocated, the internal policy can utilize the available bandwidth.

You didn't mention which device you're working with, but here's an overview of BWM policies from Sonicwall:  http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/7630/ui2/70/Policies_Firewall_BWM_Snwls.html